# Saving Object Pattern - 1to1 relationship - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns

I work on an ASP .Net MVC 5 project with EntityFramework. I'm quite new on these frameworks.

I've 2 classes bound with a one-to-one relationship :

First class : **Address**

```
 public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Meeting Meeting { get; set; }

    public virtual double Latitude { get; set; }
    public virtual double Longitude { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whole address as a string
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ToString()
    {
        return StreetAddress + " " + PostCode + " " + City + ", " + Country;
    }

}
```

Second class : **Meeting**

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

The Meeting Class is responsible for the relationship, which means I've written a **MeetingService** class to deal with simple CRUD operations. Here's the interface :

```
public interface IMeetingService
{
    IEnumerable<Meeting> GetMeetings();
    IEnumerable<Meeting> GetMeetings(int sellerId);
    Meeting GetMeeting(int id);
    void CreateMeeting(Meeting Meeting);
    void EditMeeting(Meeting MeetingToEdit);
    void DeleteMeeting(int id);
    void SaveMeeting();
}
```

My problem is that I've programmed a reverse geocoding function that updates the Latitude and Longitude fields on the Address Object (with Google MapsApi) and I'm a bit lost on where to call that function.

```
static void UpdateAdressCoordinates(ref Address address);
```

My first bet was to add some kind of trigger on the setters of the Address Properties and update the Lat/Lng each time other fields are modified but it feels kind of wrong (dont't want to had any sort of dependencies on my domain objects, even if I abstract the GoogleMaps interface)

Putting the reverse geocoding logic in the MVC controller feels wrong as well. No need to explain.

I guess I should put the logic in the service Layer then but I'm confused on how to do it properly as I'm only deeling with a Meeting object (not an "Address").

Thanks!

Comment: at edit/create level "post a message" to a "[bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus)". Write the bus, as an **independent application**, to update the coordinate of addresses according to posted message. Optionally handle a property to check whether or not coordinates and addresses are sync.